# Groovy Code converting list as a defined string Using Regex

Tags: regex, groovy

How can I do the same in groovy using regular expression(regex) :
Whenever I will find "OK" in one item of a list I need to remove "OK" including inverted comma of the whole item. I did it using loop. Here is my raw code of groovy language. Kindly help me by showing me the way of doing the same in groovy (by using Regular Expression (regex))

```
def List l = ["a","OKb","c","d"]
def s = '"' + l.join('","') + '"'
println s
String[] S_Arr = s.split(',')
int len = S_Arr.size()
for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
    if(S_Arr[i].contains("OK")){
        S_Arr[i] = S_Arr[i].replace("OK", "")
        S_Arr[i] = S_Arr[i].replace('"', "")
        S_Arr[i] = S_Arr[i].replace('"', "")
    }
}
println S_Arr

**Input :** 
def List l = ["a","OKb","c","d"]


**Output :**
["a", b, "c", "d"]
```

Comment: So your logic is if the string contains `OK`, remove that and the double quotes in the string. If the string does not contain `OK`, leave the double quotes unchanged?

Comment: Exactly..... but my query is how it can be done by using regex in groovy ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to come up with a regex to do the transformation you're looking for, but it won't always be very readable.

Here's a pattern that does that replacement

```
def l = ['"a"', '"OKb"', '"c"', '"d"']
def result = l.collect{it.replaceAll('"(.*)OK(.*)"', '$1$2')}
```

I think that's less readable than something like

```
def result = l.collect{it.contains('OK') ? it.replaceAll('OK|"', '') : it}
```

Both output `["a", b, "c", "d"]`.